# Need to combine 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Taking a deep breath, really don't know how to combine 2 tables from my MySQL, 
I will show you the tables which I've and the rows which needed to be combinated.

Table called `post`:
[image]

As you see `cat` means Category, which category it is (see below category table `nameID` is same as `cat` here)
For example my page www.site.com/category.php?nameid=NAMEID(table category)&id=ID(table post) Need to be combined so if I go to ?nameid=1&id8 the page should be blanc or giving an error since id=8 is category 2 and not 1.

[image]

```
    // BEGIN OF SHOWING CONTENT PAGE
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $naamID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
        $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $idnext = $id + 1;
        $gn     = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE nameID='".$naamID."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $go     = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $gnn    = mysql_query($gn) or die(mysql_error());
        $goo    = mysql_query($go) or die(mysql_error());
        $gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn);
        $gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo);


        if(empty($gooo['youtube'])){
        } else {
?>      <h2> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h2><br />
<?php
        echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$gooo["youtube"].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />';

        }

            if(empty($gooo['pic'])){
            } else {
            ?> <h2> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h2><br /> 
            <?php
            echo '<img src="'.$gooo["pic"].'"/>';
            }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: you wnated to get data from both the tables ?

Comment: I want when I go to my main post page for example: `www.site.com/category.php?nameid=NAMEID(table category)&id=ID(table post)`  `?nameid=1<CATEGORY 1>&id=6<ID POST THAT HAS AS ROW 'CAT' 1>` So when I go to `?nameid=1&id=6` I receive a error like 'This post doesn't exist on this category'

Comment: @Hadscape Check that if query is returning null or not when joining both given ids by `is_null()` or `empty()`. If it is the `echo` to the user that data is not available

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.keyid FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.keyid FROM table2
```

i wish this example help you ,try to understand how to combine 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on what I understood, following code snippet may solve your problem

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT p.cat, c.nameID FROM post p INNER JOIN category c ON p.cat = c.nameID WHERE p.cat = '".$id."' AND c.nameID = '".$naamID."' LIMIT 1");
 if(mysql_num_rows($row)==0)
 {
     echo("This post doesn't exist on this category")
 }
```

**Update 2:**

```
<?if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
      $naamID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
      $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
      $row1 = mysql_query("SELECT p.cat, c.nameID FROM post p INNER JOIN category c ON p.cat = c.nameID WHERE p.cat = '".$id."' AND c.nameID = '".$naamID."' LIMIT 1");
     if(mysql_num_rows($row1)==0)
     {
     echo("This post doesn't exist on this category");
     }
     else
     {          
       $idnext = $id + 1;
       $gn     = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE nameID='".$naamID."'") or die(mysql_error());
       $go     = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
       $gnn    = mysql_query($gn) or die(mysql_error());
       $goo    = mysql_query($go) or die(mysql_error());
       $gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn);
       $gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo);

       /*--------------your other display code when data is available-------------*/
      }
}     
?>
```

Comment: I don't know where to post this; still got the same error: http://pastebin.com/tsJNc4xA I've put your script there in. thank you

Comment: @Hadscape Check Update 2

Comment: He gives an error when he is on the right category. he says this post doesn't excist on this category

Comment: @Hadscape Have you checked the query in mysql ? are you getting the desired result from the query?

Comment: $naamID and @id ...try to check by echo that are they even getting values from your query string

Answer (score 0):

I think i don't understand need of passing categid, as post id itself looks like primary key, so you must able to fetch particular post record, and can retrieve name of that category which is linked with requested post using something like(you just need to pass post id in parameter)

```
SELECT youtube,title,c.name,pic  FROM post p 
INNER JOIN categories c
ON c.nameid=p.cat
WHERE p.id=2
```

If you are trying to get **requested post** record along with **all posts from requested category** than you can write query like

```
  SELECT youtube,title,c.name,pic 
  FROM post 
  INNER JOIN categories c
  ON c.nameid=p.cat
  WHERE (p.id=8 or cat=2)
```

Hope this will help!

Thanks 
Suresh